# Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found , RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, websphere-7

I developed a RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) using IBM WebSphere Application Server V7, and in executing the url : “http://localhost:9080/Conference/resources/Conference/”, the exception `Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found : /resources/Conference` launch, the same for the url “http://localhost:9080/Conference/resources/Conference/1”. 
Here are the 3 classes and the `web.wml` file :

*Conference.java*

```
package co.ma.jaxrs;
public class Conference {
        public final String name;
        public final String date;
        public final String url;

        public Conference(String name, String date, String url) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.date = date;
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
```

*ConferenceRessource.java*

```
package co.ma.jaxrs;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Conference")
public class ConferenceRessource {

    private static List<Conference> conferences = new ArrayList<Conference>();
    static {
        conferences.add(new Conference("Nom 1 ", "Mardi 12 Novembre",
                "http://google.com"));
        conferences.add(new Conference("Nom 2 ", "Jeudi 1 Octobre",
                "http://youtube.com"));
        conferences.add(new Conference("Nom 3 ", "Lundi 5 Janvier",
                "http://facebook.com"));
    };

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Conference> getList() {
        return conferences;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Conference getConferenceById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return conferences.get(id);
    }
}
```

*TestApplication.java*

```
package co.ma.jaxrs;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(ConferenceRessource.class);
        return classes;
    }

}
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Conference</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you post your log output from server startup to the point where you see the 404?  It is possible that the context root is different than what you are expecting or that there was some deployment error/warning in the logs that might provide a hint as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Remove entry from web.xml. You either configure JAX-RS via web.xml or via class with `@ApplicationPath` annotation. Not both.

Answer (score 1):

Expose a **test resource in TestApplication.java** as below and check if you can reach it out or not

```
`   
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(ConferenceRessource.class);
        return classes;
    }

@Path("/test")
public void printDebug(){
    System.out.println("got debug here");
}

}`
```

url: http://localhost:9080/Conference/resources/test